# Recent book on PIE and older proto-languages?

Tags: reference-request, proto-indo-european, history

Please recommend a recent book that summarizes and critiques the current state of knowledge and speculation on PIE and older proto-languages.  (book, please, I will have no electronic contact with the world for 2 weeks.)

Comment: You're asking for an opinion, not a fact.   Also, please phrase your question as a complete sentence. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benjamin Fortson, *[Indo-European Language and Culture: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405188960)*

James Clackson, *[Indo-European Linguistics: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521653673)*

Both are recent, well-balanced treatments by scholars of repute.

Answer (score 1):

That's mostly just Greek, but maybe you'll find this useful: [Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek Language and Linguistics](http://www.brill.com/encyclopedia-ancient-greek-language-and-linguistics), G.K. Giannakis (ed.). Also -- but this is more research, not review -- [Pre-Greek](http://www.brill.com/products/book/pre-greek) by R.S.Beekes, trying to reconstruct the non-Indo-European substrate. And maybe his Comparative Indo-European Linguistics: An Introduction.

Comment: The book on Pre-Greek looks good.  I am still hoping for a critical summary of state of knowledge of pre- PIE.

Comment: That wouldn't be pre-PIE. "Pre-Greek" means the non-IE languages that were spoken in Greece and the islands before the early Greeks invaded; they've left words (famously, _mint_) in Greek and later languages whose etymology stops there. But that was at least a thousand years, and more likely two thousand years, after the Indo-European tribes started migrating, which is the end of PIE.

Comment: @jlawler: My understanding was that ab2 asked for ``older proto-languages'' as well, that's why.

Comment: Beekes's reconstruction of pre-Greek is highly controversial. There is no consensus about this.

Comment: By "older proto-languages", I meant to say "older than PIE", but the pre-Greek also is interesting.  As for highly controversial, I am getting the feeling from browsing this forum that anything on the subject of old proto-languages worth reading is controversial.

Comment: Sure. There's been controversy enough about I-E for the last two centuries. The comparative method has an upper limit of about 6 ky; that's a liberal limit. But it means that no analysis of any language from its descendants' properties can possibly reconstruct a language that existed more than 6000 years before those descendants. So, though there is no doubt that people have been talking for 100,000 years, or very possibly 200,000 or more, we don't know how they were talking. And we never will. Language is sound, and sounds leave no fossils, apart from their fleeting influence on other sounds.

Comment: "Pre-Greek" may have been IE, or non-IE, or both (if there was more than one language spoken in Greece at the time, which is hardly unlikely). No one really knows.

Comment: I have ordered "Pre-Greek", and both the Fortson and Clackson books.  No further questions until I have read these books.

Comment: @TKR The idea Pre-Greek was IE has failed badly so many times that I doubt anyone will ever raise a brow for such a theory for at least 20 more years. Besides, Beekes mentions the damage all those old "Pelasgian" theories caused, which were basically the main reason that (except from Furnee) not many people dared to write much about the subject for decades. It is more likely that Pre-Greek was a near eastern pre-Semitic "agricultural" language(s) which in turn had an earlier hunter-gatherer or some kind of Old European substrate in it.

Comment: @Midas I believe the idea that Anatolian languages may have been spoken in Greece still has some currency, though of course given the scantiness of the evidence it's hard to prove or disprove anything at all about "pre-Greek".

Comment: @TKR I believe that idea as well, but a modified version of it. Greece was the first place in Europe where farming spread and farming came from Anatolia/Near East, hence a language from there must have been carried over. An Anatolian language, but of non-IE origin. The Anatolian Indo-European words in Greek are a hand full, while the agricultural vocabulary of Greek and the words considered pre-Greek are clearly non-IE. While Palmers "Luwian invasion of Greece" was once tempting, I tend to strongly agree with Kroonen and Scheijvers pre-IE version. Also Beekes demonstrates that PG was not IE.

Answer (score 1):

My pick would be:

Mallory, James P., and Douglas Q. Adams. [The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-oxford-introduction-to-proto-indo-european-and-the-proto-indo-european-world-9780199296682?cc=us&lang=en&). Oxford University Press on Demand, 2006.

There is a great lexical material inside, including sub-groupings of Indo-European e.g. Graeco-Aryan etc. The style of writing is literally 'easy reading'. I like the book a lot and so do people who bought it if you judge from the reviews.